# How to group by a range of promises with underscore?

Tags: javascript, promise, underscore.js, bluebird

I can successfully collect metrics from redis but I also want to collect it by device id. What is the simplest way to do that?

Here, I'm using underscore & bluebird.

**Desired object:**

```js
[
  { 
    deviceId    : 'foo',

    stats: [
      {
        date        : '20160215',
        temperature : 32.3,
        uptime      : 10.0,
        frequency   : 0.2
      },
      {
        date        : '20160216',
        temperature : 12.3,
        uptime      : 15.0,
        frequency   : 0.3
      }
      // ,...
    ]
  },

  { 
    deviceId    : 'bar',

    stats: [
      {
        date        : '20160215',
        temperature : 42.3,
        uptime      : 0.3,
        frequency   : 0.5
      },
      {
        date        : '20160216',
        temperature : 32.3,
        uptime      : 1.2,
        frequency   : 0.5
      }
      // ,...
    ]
  }
]
```

**Data stored in redis in a sorted set:**

```
// metric:device:device-id:daily

temperature:device:standart-faf4-4279-a040-0e729e53f5c1:daily
uptime:device:standart-faf4-4279-a040-0e729e53f5c1:daily
frequency:device:standart-faf4-4279-a040-0e729e53f5c1:daily
```

**My code:**

```js
  var metrics = [ 'temperature', 'uptime', 'frequency' ];

  var signals = _
    .chain(statsOfToday)
    .pluck('deviceId')
    .map(function(deviceId) {
      return _.map(metrics, function(metric) {
        return redis.zrangebyscoreAsync(
          metric +":device:"+ deviceId +":daily",
          20160215, 20160216
        );
      })
    })
    .flatten()
    .value();

  // in here deviceId is lost
  return Promise.all(signals)
    .then(function(results) {
      return _
        .chain(results)
        .flatten()
        .map(function(x) {
          // data in redis stored as: metric-timestamp
          return x.split("-")[0];
        })
        .value();
    });
```

Comment: What's `rows` in your code sample?

Comment: @Tomalak oops, sorry. ```rows``` should have been ```signals```

Comment: `metrics` is also not really defined. A sample of the expected output would help as well.

Comment: @Tomalak ok, sure i've updated the code example. expected output is the ```desired object``` at the top.

Comment: Did it work? (I'm asking because an accept without a comment often indicates the OP not really being satisfied with the answer)

Comment: @Tomalak yes, it has worked. but, the result is not in the format of the ```desired object``` I needed. It has returned: ```[ { deviceId: '...', metric: 'temperature', data: [ '10-20160215', '4-20160216' ], ... ]```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103862/discussion-between-deeperx-and-tomalak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that your first statement results in an array of promises for values that don't contain the deviceId they refer to, which makes processing them harder in the second step.

How about this, then:

```
var signals = _
  .chain(statsOfToday)
  .pluck('deviceId')
  .map(function(deviceId) {
    return _.map(metrics, function(metric) {
      return redis.zrangebyscoreAsync(
        metric +":device:"+ deviceId +":daily", 20160215, 20160216
      ).then(function (data) {
        return data.map(function (item) {
            return {
              deviceId: deviceId,
              metric: metric,
              data: item.split("-")[0]
            };
        });
      });
    })
  })
  .flatten()
  .value();
```

This way you get an array of promises for values that contain `deviceId`, `metric` and the associated `data` that came from Redis.

Grouping data/massaging it into shape can happen after that in `Promise.all(signals)`.

---

Nicer to read and easier to reuse:

```
function getDeviceMetricAsync(deviceId, metric, min, max) {
  var key = metric + ":device:" + deviceId + ":daily";
  return redis.zrangebyscoreAsync(key, min, max).map(function (item) {
    return {
      deviceId: deviceId,
      metric: metric,
      data: item.split("-")[0]
    }
  });
}


var signals = _
  .chain(statsOfToday)
  .pluck('deviceId')
  .map(function(deviceId) {
    var retrievalFunc = _.partial(getDeviceMetricAsync, deviceId, _, 20160215, 20160216);
    return _.map(metrics, retrievalFunc);
  })
  .flatten()
  .value();
```

**Note:** The line `redis.zrangebyscoreAsync(key, min, max).map(...)` assumes that the Redis API uses Bluebird promises, i.e. `var Promise = require('Bluebird');` should be done before importing Redis.

The vanilla Promise API does not support `.map()`, you'd have to do that manually if Redis has its own Promise implementation.

Comment: bluebird supports map. and here xxxAsync is a bluebird asynced redis api.